# Forum xml to redirect link

Tags: php, xml

How to take the link example2.com

```
<response>
<redirect>
example2.com
</redirect>
<code>0</code>
<description>OK</description>
</response>
```

from another page  which in   XML basics(information) based  on  example.com link

Comment: How have you tried it yet?

Comment: So what did you do? What went wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`simplexml_load_string()` function parse the `xml` string and return array.

```
$xml = '<?xml version='1.0'?><response>
<redirect>
example2.com
</redirect>
<code>0</code>
<description>OK</description>
</response>';

$array = simplexml_load_string($xml);

print_r($xml);
```